# Query either or condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want query mongoDB in such a way that I pass in a query in the form of an array of Objects. 
Each object is in the form of

```
{
name: "<someName>",
someArr: [<someArr>]
}
```

Now, I want to query the database in such a way that for a document to fit the query, it must fulfill two conditions:

1. The document must have the same **name** as either one of the query's object name attribute.
2. The document's **someArr** attribute must be a subset of the query's object's **someArr** provided condition 1 is true.

If the query is a single object, I can query it be using $match and $unwind.

So I would like to know if it is possible to do a query with an array of objects for mongoDB or do I have to loop for each query Object?

Thanks

An Example:

If query is:

```
[
  {name: "test", someArr: [1,2]},
  {name: "test2", someArr: [3]}
]
```

And the database contains the following:

```
[
{name: "test3", someArr: [1,2]},
{name: "test", someArr: [1]},
{name: "test2", someArr: [4]}
]
```

The results of the query should be

```
[{name: "test", someArr: [1]}]
```

Since only it match both conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to "aggregate" anything here. This is a simple query. All you do is transform your initial "query array" into the actual query DSL required. And that's simply putting an [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) on the `someArr` and feeding the whole array to [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
var conditions = [
  {name: "test", someArr: [1,2]},
  {name: "test2", someArr: [3]}
];

db.collection.find({
  "$or": conditions.map( c => Object.assign(c, { someArr: { "$in": c.someArr } }) )
})
```

For clarity, that's transform produces this from the source array:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {name: "test", someArr: { "$in": [1,2] } },
    {name: "test2", someArr: { "$in": [3] } }
  ]
})
```

And that returns the correct document.

A "sub-set" effectly means "shares at least one of the elements", and that is what [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) does as a query operator. So there is no need to do any further calculation unless it is for projection purposes.

Comment: But I need to check the name matches, before checking the array. Does your query do the name checking?

Comment: @CodingNoobie It does.` Object.assign()` is a "merge" of the existing object with new data. So all I am doing here is overwriting `someArr` in each array item with an included `$in` key. Showing the full expanded query result of `.map()` so you can clearly see it.